# Probability density function of Z where Z=X/Y, X,Y are exp random variables with parameter is 1?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What I thought is, for any a that Z = a, if Y = y, then X should be ay. The probability X = ay and Y = y is $e^{-ay}e^{-y}$. Then take intergal $\int_{0}^{\infty } e^{-y}e^{-ay}dy=\frac{1}{a+1}$.

But it's not the right answer, right answer is $\frac{1}{(1+a)^{2}}$.

I use the other method that calculate $F_{Z}(z)$ first then derivative it and gets the right p.d.f. But I am confused where my thinking above is wrong...

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? Never take independence for granted.

Comment: $P(X=ay, Y=y)$ is $0$. You are treating $X$ and $Y$ as discrete random variables.

Comment: Yes, they are independent

Comment: I take integral for p.d.f

Answer (score 1):

You missed the Jacobian determinant.   The transformation $\langle Z,Y\rangle\mapsto\langle ZY,Y\rangle$ is not colinear.   You have to apply the chain rule.

$$\begin{align}f_{\small Z}(z) &=\int_\Bbb R f_{\small Z,Y}(z,y)\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&= \int_\Bbb R \left\lVert\dfrac{\partial \langle zy, y\rangle}{\partial\langle z, y\rangle}\right\rVert f_{\small X,Y}(zy,y)\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&=\int_0^\infty y\,\mathrm e^{-(z+1)y}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant z}\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&=\dfrac 1{(z+1)^2}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant z}\int_0^\infty u\,\mathrm e^{-u}\;\mathrm d u&&u:=(z+1)y, \mathrm d u:=(z+1)\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1}{(z+1)^2}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant z}\end{align}$$

---

**Alternatively**

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Z\leqslant z)&=\int_{\Bbb R^+}\mathsf P(Z\leqslant z\mid Y=y)\,f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex] &=\int_{\Bbb R^+}\mathsf P(X\leqslant Yz\mid Y=y)~f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex] &=\int_{\Bbb R^+}\mathsf P(X\leqslant yz)~f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&=\int_{\Bbb R^+}\int_{0}^{yz} f_{\small X}(x)\,f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\[2ex]f_{\small Z}(z)&=\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathsf P(Z\leqslant z)}{\mathrm d z} \\[1ex]&=\int_{\Bbb R^+}\, y f_{\small X}(yz)\,f_{\small Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random variables with densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$, then the density of the ratio $Z:= \frac XY$ is given by
$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{\mathbb R} |y|f_X(zy)f_Y(y)\ \mathsf dy.
$$
In the case where $X\sim\mathsf{Expo}(\lambda)$, $Y\sim\mathsf{Expo}(\mu)$ we have
\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= \int_0^\infty y\lambda e^{-\lambda zy}\mu e^{-\mu y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \lambda\mu \int_0^\infty ye^{-(\lambda z+\mu)y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac{\lambda  \mu }{(\mu +\lambda  z)^2}.
\end{align}
If $\lambda=\mu=1$ this simplifies to
$$
f_Z(z) = \frac1{(1+z)^2}\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(z).
$$